# How to use installer variables in the uninstaller?

Tags: java, install4j

Here is my use case, so that you can understand why I need an uninstaller.
I have to modify the content of a WAR file chosen in a screen with a file chooser, back it up with the database first, then modify the database, and then the WAR.
The modification of the WAR and the database works like a charm, so does the backup, but then I need to give to the end user the possibility, to restore the previous WAR and database as easily as, he modified them.

For that I created some actions which will use the backup files, and the installer runtime variables, but I have an error showing at the execution of the uninstaller, saying that it couldn't load the main class.

I just don't use any launcher, because in fact I am not trying to install any software, just doing some files manipulations.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to restore the backup files using the uninstallation?
2. Is it possible to use installer variables in other applications?

**Edit:**

In the uninstaller, I need to use form components variables from the installer, and other variables that I created using the "Set a Variable" action in the installer too, for which I have to check the Register to Response File checkbox.

Then in the startup node of the uninstaller, after the "Request privileges" action, I add the "Load response file" action, and leave the "File" textfield empty, so it could load
the default response file created by the installer.
I then call those variables in the uninstaller's subsequent actions with 
 `${installer:variableName}`
, like you said, but I get an error dialog saying this:

[image]

with this stack in the log file that gets generated:

```
Exception:

com.install4j.api.beans.UndefinedVariableException: installer:zPath
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables$InstallerReplacementCallback.handleError(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables$InstallerReplacementCallback.getReplacement(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.util.StringUtil.replaceVariable(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.api.beans.AbstractBean.replaceVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.AbstractFileAction.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.AbstractFileAction.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.SystemInstallOrUninstallAction.uninstall(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.UninstallerContextImpl$2.fetchValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.FetchObjectAction.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionWrapper(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

I get two other error dialogs for another variable, here is its stack:

```
Exception:

com.install4j.api.beans.UndefinedVariableException: installer:zLoc
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables$InstallerReplacementCallback.handleError(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables$InstallerReplacementCallback.getReplacement(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.util.StringUtil.replaceVariable(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.api.beans.AbstractBean.replaceVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction.getExecutable(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.SystemInstallOrUninstallAction.uninstall(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.UninstallerContextImpl$2.fetchValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.FetchObjectAction.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionWrapper(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication$1.run(Unknown Source)

Exception:

com.install4j.api.beans.UndefinedVariableException: installer:zLoc
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables$InstallerReplacementCallback.handleError(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables$InstallerReplacementCallback.getReplacement(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.util.StringUtil.replaceVariable(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.api.beans.AbstractBean.replaceVariables(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.AbstractFileAction.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.AbstractFileAction.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.SystemInstallOrUninstallAction.uninstall(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.UninstallerContextImpl$2.fetchValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.FetchObjectAction.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionWrapper(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: On the "Install files" action, is the "Install files" action property selected?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but I used the "install files" action inside a "Configurable banner form" screen.

Comment: Sorry, that was garbled, the question should have been:  On the "Install files" action, is the "Install runtime" property selected?

Comment: Yes, it is selected.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace that you get or a screen shot of the error message?

Comment: There isn't much, it's just a simple error box saying: "Couldn't load main class", where can I get the full stack?

Comment: OK, is there a directory .install4j in the installation directory? In that directory there must be a file i4jruntime.jar which contains the main class

Comment: Well, actually, I found what I did wrong, I was copying i4jruntime.jar and uninstall.exe only, I copied the whole .install4j foder with uninstall.exe, and now the uninstaller works, but still gives me an UndefinedVariableException which answers my second question.
But, how could I use the values of the  installer variables in the uninstaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to restore the backup files using the uninstallation?

This has been resolved in the comments above.

> Is it possible to use installer variables in other applications?

Yes, add a "Load a response file" action to the "Startup" node of the uninstaller. The variable must be a response file variable. All variables that are bound to form components are automatically registered for the response file. For other variables, there is a check box when you pre-define an installer variable on the "Installer variables" tab of the installer configuration. Alternatively, you can call

```
context.registerResponseFileVariable(...);
```

in a "Run script" action in the installer.

In the uninstaller, you can then use those response file variables in text fields with the syntax `${installer:variableName}` or in scripts via `context.getVariable("variableName")`.

Comment: Ok I created a response file at the final screen of the installer, in which I could see the variables that I need, after I add the "load response file" action in the uninstaller, how do I access those variables in the subsequent actions?

Comment: Ok thanks to your directions I'm very close to achieve my solution, but I'm still having pretty much the same problem, I can see the registred variables in the response file, but when I use them in the uninstaller, at runtime it gives me an error, I will edit my question so I can show you the stack I get.

Comment: Do you have a "load response file" action in the startup node of the uninstaller?

Comment: Yes, as I said I edited my question, with all the details related to my problem.

Comment: Please send the install4j project file and the response file (.install4j\response.varfile) to support@ej-technologies.com

Comment: Ok, thank you for your support. I still have some last questions though, I remarked that response.varfile, files.log and installation.log gets created after the end of the installation. which means that I can't use them during the installation. Is this the normal behaviour?
Is there an action that could create a shorcut to those files in a custom folder?

Comment: These files are created when the "Install files" action runs. The log file is available earlier in the %TEMP% directory with a name starting with "i4jlog..."

Comment: I delete the .install4j folder entirely, but after the end of the installation it gets recreated with only the files I mentioned above. I need to give the client the possiblity to give me a feedback on the war update, but I guess that I will have to tell them to find it in the installation folder.
As for my problem, I found an alternative solution, I created another install4j project to restore the backup, and placed its executable in the main install4j project's distribution tree, it works just fine.
I want to thank you for your time.